# What does the "see reduced ads" privilege mean?

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, advertising

Supposedly I just earned this privilege. I clicked on the link and it took me to a page that lists a whole bunch of other privileges but not "see reduced ads". It's not like this website is brimming with ads to begin with (another browser tab I have open has ads for Norwegian Cruise Lines, University of Nebraska and Viagra, and that's just without scrolling down).

According to the privileges page, I have "vote down" privilege and I'm close to earning "view close votes" privilege. I don't know what the latter is, but there's a page that explains it and will tell me if it really is what I think it is. Is there such a page for "see reduced ads"?

Comment: Check [on Stack Overflow's help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads). Not all sites have the ads that are reduced by that privilege.

Comment: Where did you see a link saying you had earned the "reduce ads" privilege?

Comment: @JarrodDixon From OP's description it appears to be "Congratulations, you have earned" on the new user profile, Activity page.

Comment: @Yes good call, I'll check that out now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some SE sites (for example the trilogy sites Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault) have actual advertisements, and an actual [reduce ads privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) which disables the full-width ads which appear on these sites. Here's an example recently seen on Stack Overflow:

> [image: New Relic Browser ad]

Mathematics Stack Exchange is *not* one of the SE sites which have these advertisements ([full list here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243521)), and from [Shog9's answer on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246563), if you were notified of earning this here it would be a bug as

> on most sites, it's hidden and notifications for earning it are suppressed.

Answer (score 13):

There was a bug where a disabled privilege could still show up when congratulating you for earning one.

This has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick resolution :).

Comment: Indeed. In my case, it now says I've gained the vote down privilege.