# Are there ads on Mathematics Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, bug, advertising

As far as I can tell, ads are displayed on some sites in the Stack Exchange network. (At least for users below some reputation threshold.) But I saw some contradictory information concerning the question whether there are ads on this site.

Some places which say we do not have ads:

- These posts have lists of sites the where ads are enabled: [We're enabling display ads on select Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287242) ([current revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/287242/8)) and [What sites have advertisements enabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243364#243521) ([current revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/243521/24)). The lists do not include Mathematics. (A test of running ads on *all* sites is mentioned, but the edit from June 2019 says that it is only for the following 6 months, until the end of that calendar year.)
- Answer on this meta which also says there are no ads on this site: [Where does math stackexchange get its money for hosting servers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33133#33170)

Some places mentioning (showing) ads on Mathematics or with unclear information:

- A bug report on this meta which explicitly says that this site does have ads: [Privilege page on reduced ads doesn't show on this site, even though there are now advertisements](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32595). (Since the two posts were posted on the same day, it seems quite likely that this bug report was posted as a reaction to the question mentioned in the next bullet point.)
- A post on Meta Stack Exchange which shows a screenshot on this site with ads: [Ads appearing before (on top of) questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354658) (For a user with one reputation point.) The answers posted to this question claim that it is well-known fact that ads are shown to users below 200 reputation points.
- Searching [in the help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=reduced) shows: "Privilege: reduce ads - Some ads are now automatically disabled". But when I actually [click on the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) returned by that search, I am only redirected to the list of privileges. (I can see such privileges on some other sites, such as: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads), [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads), [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads).)
- On some sites I can also see an option to display more ads - but not on Mathematics. For example, this is what I get on Meta Stack Exchange:

[image: Screenshot from Meta Stack Exchange]

Thanks to Calvin Khor, who [mentioned to me some of these links](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/110884/2021/3/13) in chat.

**Main question.** Are ads supposed to be displayed on Mathematics Stack Exchange? If they are displayed, is it to users below 200 reputation points (as on other sites)?

- If not, was the instance in the [linked Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354658) (which has screenshots of ads) simply a bug?
- If yes, shouldn't the information in various places be updated to reflect his information? (Such as the help center on this site, the users' preferences or the [list of the sites which have ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243364/what-sites-have-advertisements-enabled#243521).)

To clarify, I do not mean [community ads](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-ads/info). I am aware that they exist on this site [for about a decade now](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/community-promotion-ads-2012).

Comment: I remember that Meta post I wrote very well about an ad appearing on math.se.  Thanks for looking into this, as well as thanks to Calvin Khor, and for posting this here.

Comment: There’s no need to thank me for my mediocre searching skills :) hope this gets an authoritative answer

Comment: Unbelievable that such an important question has remained unanswered for so long.

Comment: It [seems](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33689/how-to-keep-ads-from-appearing-on-stack-exchange?noredirect=1&lq=1) that there are ads now. I don't see them (presumably due to being unable to load them for various reasons) Can you confirm they exist (maybe they are still in A/B stage?), and is it worth asking for an update to [We're testing advertisements across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network)?